# UPS 120v and 230v

Tags: ups

I would like to know about a UPS.  The APC international model is a 220/230v where in Canada our plugs are 120v.

if I could push 230v to the international UPS (installing 15A plug) and switch my computers from the standard 120v to 230v on the computer power supply would that work or would I fry something up?

Answer (score 0):

As long as You are supplying 220V from the wall to a UPS rated 220V and plugging devices into the UPS rated for 220V, I see no reason that wouldn't work.